# Returning all values from an array in an exercise

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, return-value

I'm at the moment learning some PHP through a website where they give you exercises. Up until now I've done them without that much of a difficulty, but this one specific exercise, I can't do. I've looked at it for 8 hours without any progress, and also asked from 3 of my friends. None of them know how to do it properly.

Anyways, the exercise would return all values of an array (with a space between them, NOT comma!), plus also a sum and average of them. The exercise gives you some code already, which you CAN'T edit. The code is this:

```
<?php

$lukujono = $_GET['lukujono'];
$lukutaulukko = explode(',',$lukujono);

// Your code is put here, and here only.

echo "Points are: $points\n";
echo "The sum of points: $sum\n";
echo "The average of points: $average";
?>
```

At the moment, I have this done and which is correct, it seems:

```
$sum = array_sum($lukutaulukko);
$average = $sum / (count($lukutaulukko));
```

However, the problem for me is to list all the values in the array without the comma. For now, this is the closes I've got:

```
foreach ($lukutaulukko as $points){
$points = str_replace(',', ' ', $points);
}
```

However, this code only prints out the last value. I know that they get overwritten, so... how to get them like this?

```
Points are: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**implode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to turn your array back into a string, with first param serving as a separator.

```
$points = implode(' ', $lukutaulukko);
```